# Count elements in nested lists based on another list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to count how many times a word within nested lists occur based on a different word list. For example:

```
one = [['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]
word = ['pear','oranges','pineapple','scones','drawers']
```

I want to count how many times each word in the list word occurs in each nested list called `one`. As output I want:

```
new_one = [[0,1,0],[0,1,0,0]]
```

I tried using `.count` but `.count` does not use elements within a list, but single string or integers. I couldn't use for loop to index elements of word using `.count()`. The same is for Counter, which does not seem to work for nested lists, or within a for loop.

I could think of using dictionaries but ultimately I want `new_one` to be a list of lists, since I want to later turn new_one into a matrix where one row is a row of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
one = [['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]
word = ['pear','oranges','pineapple','scones','drawers']
output = []

# create a dict and populate with keys being unique words and values being its occurances
d = {}

for x in one:
    for y in x:
        d[y] = word.count(y)

# go through each word in sublist and find the count from the dict
for x in ne:
    output.append([d[y] for y in x])
```

This should give you:

```
output = [[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach:

```
[[[1 if z == x else 0 for z in y] for y in one] for x in word]
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: This is great, but could this work when apple occurs twice?

Comment: Of course!! If `one` was `one = [['apple','pear'','bear', 'pear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]`, the output would include a 1 in the new slot where `pear` is. Try it! :)

Comment: oh ok, would there be a way to count them though...? for apple, return two?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[word.count(w) for w in l] for l in one]
```

This is slightly inefficient because it counts the occurences of each word every time (e.g. it'll perform `word.count('apple')` twice), but if your lists aren't very long it won't be a problem.

Comment: What is word here? if it refers to the nested list, it wound't work.

Answer (score 0):

First we iterate the out list ie one. For each list in one we iterate the elements ie apple pear bear etc. If this matches the list word then we append to temporary list new_one_temp. In each outer iteration we append to new_one list.

```
one=[['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]
word=['pear','oranges','pineapple','scones','drawers']

new_one=[]
for list_elem in one:
    new_one_temp=[]
    for word_text in list_elem:
        if word_text in word:
            new_one_temp.extend([1])
        else:
            new_one_temp.extend([0])
    new_one.append(new_one_temp)
print new_one
```

Output

```
new_one = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```